# How to avoid multiple loops for array computations?

Tags: r, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have a (large) array that I need to compute. The array has three dimensions, but so far I have only been able to do the first dimension without a loop (and the other two dimensions by a written-out loop).

```
y <- array(0.0, dim = c(numberScenarios, (numberYears + 1), numberMaturities))
for (t in 1:(numberYears + 1)){
  for (tau in 1:numberMaturities){
    y[, t, tau] <- exp(- (phi[tau, t] + psi[tau, 1] * x1[, t] +
                            psi[tau, 2] * x2[, t] +
                            psi[tau, 3] * x3[, t]) / tau) - 1}}
```

Any computation of `y` does not involve itself, so there is no recursion that requires a loop.

So, is there a way to approach this in a more matrix-algebraic (and possibly faster) way?

Note that all variables have the right size for such a computation.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me what you are trying to do.  However for multi-dimensional calculations, using input vectors of different lengths  it is often easier to use the `expand.grid` function rather than an array and then process the rows of the resulting dataframe.  E.g.

```
a <- 1:4
b <- 1:2
c <- 1:5
df <- expand.grid(a = a, b = b, c = c)
head(df)
1 1 1 1
2 2 1 1
3 3 1 1
4 4 1 1
5 1 2 1
6 2 2 1
result <- 2 * df[1] - df[2] + 4 * df[3]
head(result)
   a
1  5
2  7
3  9
4 11
5  4
6  6
```

If this method maps to your problem a, b and c would be your input vectors and result would a function that you define

Answer (score 0):

Consider assigning by whole vectors instead of individual elements if possible:

```r
t <- 1:(numberYears + 1)
tau <- 1:numberMaturities

y[, t, tau] <- exp(
  -(
      phi[tau, t] + 
      psi[tau, 1] * x1[, t] + 
      psi[tau, 2] * x2[, t] + 
      psi[tau, 3] * x3[, t]
  ) / tau
) - 1
```

Comment: Ah, I was thinking "how do I get multiple "free" indexes in there" and this is very elegant. However, it doesn't work in this case. "Error in phi[tau, t] + (psi[tau, 1]) * (x1[, t]) : non-conformable arrays"

Comment: As mentioned *if possible*. Sample data of all these objects would help for a [mre]. From my end, they can be anything. Your loop treats each as single element entities but matrix product require knowing dimensions.